# Why dialog for enabling dangerous android permissions is shown 2 times?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am developing an app where I am using android's dialog for granting dangerous permissions. And when I click button for login on LoginActivity I go to Main activity and dialog is show. But when I press BACK button, again this dialog appears! This is my  MainActivity(Just to say that my launcher activity is MAinActivity, not LoginActivity):

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bugsnag.init(this, BUGSNAG_API_KEY);
        company_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.company_name);
        aUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);

        company_name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorBlue));
//        aUsername.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorBlack));

        toolbarImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_id);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        }

        getDataForToolbar();

        checkIfServiceWorking();
        askingForPermissionInManifest();
        alertForEnablingGPS();
        logoutWhenCompanyDisabled();

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("FCM", "Fire_base token is: " + token);

        readTokenFromSharedPreferences();

        initializeInjectorListIcons();
        initializeListIcons();

        initializeInjector();
        initialize();

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                getFragment(tabId);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Context getContx() {
        return mContext;
    }

    private void checkIfServiceWorking() {
        mLocationService = new LocationService(getContx());
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(getContx(), mLocationService.getClass());
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(LocationService.class)){
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", true + "");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i ("isMyServiceRunning?", false + "");
        return false;
    }

    private void initializeInjector() {
        this.accountComponent = DaggerAccountComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
                .activityModule(getActivityModule())
                .accountModule(new AccountModule())
                .build();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        this.getComponent(AccountComponent.class).inject(this);
        this.accountPresenter.setView(this);
        this.accountPresenter.initialize();
    }

    public void initializeInjectorListIcons() {
        this.accountComponent = DaggerAccountComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
                .activityModule(getActivityModule())
                .listIconsModule(new ListIconsModule())
                .build();
    }

    public void initializeListIcons() {
        this.getComponent(AccountComponent.class).inject(this);
        this.listIconsPresenter.initializeListIcons();
    }

    @Override
    public AccountComponent getComponent() {
        return accountComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void viewAccount(AccountModel accountModel) {
        if (accountModel != null) {
            if (accountModel.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_team_leader)) || (accountModel.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_user)))){

                Gson account_json = new Gson();
                String account = account_json.toJson(accountModel);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.Account_json), MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json), account);
                editor.apply();

                List<ButtonModel> arrayListButton = accountModel.getLayout().getButtons();

                if (accountModel.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_user)) || accountModel.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_team_leader)) && arrayListButton.size() != 0) {
                    showLanguageSettings();
                    addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new DashboardFragment());
                    goingToFragmentWithNotificationClick();
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(accountModel.getUuid());
                    for (CompanyModel com : accountModel.getCompanies()) {
                        String teamUuid = com.getTeam().getUuid();
                        String language = com.getLanguage().getCode();
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("language", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences1.edit();
                        editor1.putString("prefLanguage", language);
                        editor1.apply();
                        if (teamUuid != null) {
                            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(teamUuid);
                        }
                    }
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(accountModel.getRoles().getUuid());
                } else if (arrayListButton.size() == 0 && accountModel.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_user)) || accountModel.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_team_leader))) {
                    addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new EmptyListButtonFragment());
                }
                getDataForToolbar();
            }
             else {
                removeTokenAndWrongAccountFromSharedPreferences();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_log_out) {
            if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                unsubscribingFromFirebase();
                removeTokenAndAccountFromSharedPreferences();
                shouldRestart = false;

                stopService(mServiceIntent);
                Log.i("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "Logout!");

                Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITY " , "Internet access ");
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.need_internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_fcmToken) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setHeight(300);
            textView.setText(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
            textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Token");
            builder.setView(textView)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.versionInfo) {
            getCurrentAppVersionInfo();
        }
        if (id == R.id.LocationInfo){
            getLocationInfo();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void readTokenFromSharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.token_preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String strPref = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.token), null);

        if (strPref == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void removeTokenAndAccountFromSharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.token_preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences.edit().remove(getResources().getString(R.string.token)).apply();
        final String strPref = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.token), null);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesAccount = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.Account_json), MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferencesAccount.edit().remove(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json)).apply();
        final String accountPref = sharedPreferencesAccount.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json), null);

        if (strPref == null && accountPref == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void removeTokenAndWrongAccountFromSharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.token_preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strPref;
        strPref = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.token), null);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesAccount = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.Account_json), MODE_PRIVATE);
        String accountPref;
        accountPref=sharedPreferencesAccount.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json), null);

        if(strPref != null || accountPref != null){
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove(getResources().getString(R.string.token)).apply();
            sharedPreferencesAccount.edit().remove(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json)).apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.message_for_roles), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void getFragment(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.tab_menu_dashboard:
                addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new DashboardFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.tab_menu_messages:
                addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new MessagesFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.tab_menu_team:
                addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new TeamFragment());
                break;

            case R.id.tab_menu_incidents:
                addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new IncidentsFragment());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        readTokenFromSharedPreferences();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (alertDialog != null) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (alertDialog != null) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        Log.i("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "onDestroy!");
    }

    public void goingToFragmentWithNotificationClick() {
        String clickNotification = getIntent().getStringExtra("notification_type");
        String clickReportActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("report_activity");
        if (clickNotification != null) {

            if (mAccount != null) {
                if (mAccount.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_team_leader))) {
                    if (clickNotification.equals("incident_notify")) {
                        addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new IncidentsFragment());
                    } else if (clickNotification.equals("chat_message")) {
                        addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new MessagesFragment());
                    }
                } else {
                    if (clickNotification.equals("chat_message")) {
                        addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new MessagesFragment());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(clickReportActivity!=null){
            addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, new IncidentsFragment());
        }
    }

    public void picassoLoader(Context context, ImageView imageView, String url) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .resize(70, 58)
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(8, 0))
                .into(imageView);
    }

    private void getCurrentAppVersionInfo() {
        int versionCode = -1;
        String versionName = "";
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
            versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        String alert1 = "Version Code: " + versionCode;
        String alert2 = "Version Name: " + versionName;
        builder.setMessage(alert1 + "\n" + alert2).show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void getDataForToolbar() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.Account_json), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String account = sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.account_json), null);

        if (account != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            mAccount = gson.fromJson(account, AccountModel.class);

            for (CompanyModel com : mAccount.getCompanies()) {
                String name = com.getName();
                company_name.setText(name);
                logo_url = com.getLogo_url();
            }
            if (logo_url == null || logo_url.isEmpty()) {
                Picasso
                        .with(this)
                        .load(R.drawable.default_company)
                        .resize(70, 58)
                        .transform(new RoundedTransformation(8, 0))
                        .into(toolbarImage);
            } else {
                picassoLoader(this, toolbarImage, logo_url);
            }
            String username = mAccount.getUsername();
            if(mAccount.getStatus()){
                aUsername.setText(username + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.on_duty));
                aUsername.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorGreen));
            }else{
                aUsername.setText(username + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.off_duty));
                aUsername.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorWhite));
            }

        }
    }

    public void alertForEnablingGPS() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.enable_location_Service));
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.GPS));
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public void logoutWhenCompanyDisabled() {
        String logout = getIntent().getStringExtra("notification_type");
        if (logout != null) {
            if (logout.equals("company_disabled")) {
                unsubscribingFromFirebase();
                removeTokenAndAccountFromSharedPreferences();
            }
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribingFromFirebase() {
        if (mAccount != null) {

            if (mAccount.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_user)) || mAccount.getRoles().getName().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.role_team_leader))) {
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(mAccount.getUuid());
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(mAccount.getRoles().getUuid());

                for (CompanyModel com : mAccount.getCompanies()) {
                    String teamUuid = com.getTeam().getUuid();

                    if (teamUuid != null) {
                        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(teamUuid);
                    }
                    Log.d("FCM", "UnSubscribed on team Uuid: " + teamUuid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class RoundedTransformation implements com.squareup.picasso.Transformation {
        private final int radius;
        private final int margin;

        public RoundedTransformation(final int radius, final int margin) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.margin = margin;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

            Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(margin, margin, source.getWidth() - margin, source.getHeight() - margin), radius, radius, paint);

            if (source != output) {
                source.recycle();
            }
            return output;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "rounded";
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    public void askingForPermissionInManifest(){
        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("all", "good");
                    alertForEnablingGPS();
                    restartActivity();
                } else {
                    Log.d("need location", "need permissions");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

This is LogIn activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements HasComponent<LoginComponent>, TokenView {

    Credentials credentials;
    TextInputEditText username;
    TextInputEditText password;
    Button login;
    Configuration config;
    private LoginComponent loginComponent;
    @Inject LoginPresenter loginPresenter;
    static Context mContext;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mContext = this;

        checkLanguage();

        username = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        credentials = new Credentials();
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

                if (getUsername.length()>0 && getPassword.length()>0 ) {
                    credentials.setUsername(getUsername);
                    credentials.setPassword(getPassword);

                    allOperations();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_fields , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void initializeInjector() {
        this.loginComponent = DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
                .activityModule(getActivityModule())
                .loginModule(new LoginModule(this.credentials))
                .build();
    }

    public void initialize () {
        this.getComponent(LoginComponent.class).inject(this);
        this.loginPresenter.setView(this);
        this.loginPresenter.initialize(this.credentials);
    }

    @Override
    public void viewToken(TokenModel tokenModel) {
        if (tokenModel != null) {
            String tokMod = tokenModel.getToken();

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.token_preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(getResources().getString(R.string.token), tokMod);
            editor.apply();
            Log.d("Token na logovanju je: ", "TokenLogo" + tokMod);

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void allOperations () {
        initializeInjector();
        initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public LoginComponent getComponent() {
        return loginComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void showLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void showRetry() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideRetry() {

    }

    @Override
    public void showError(int message) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public Context context() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (loginPresenter != null) {
            this.loginPresenter.destroy();
        }
    }

    public void checkLanguage(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("language", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = sharedPreferences.getString("prefLanguage", null);
        config = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
        if(language!=null){
            if(language.equals("en")){
                config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
            }
            if(language.equals("sr")){
                config.locale = new Locale("sr");
            }
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            onConfigurationChanged(config);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public static void downloadFile(String uRl, String name_image) {
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/icons");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }

        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                        | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                .setDescription("Incident icons for dashboard.")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/icons", name_image);
        mgr.enqueue(request);
    }}
```

Could anyone helps me how to fix this problem, how to get this dialog only when I login into Main activity, not when I click BACK button? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your LoginActivity code.

Comment: @AshishShukla I have edited my question with log in activity, please take a look..

Comment: What are you doing in this method restartActivity() ?

Comment: Just restart main activity because gps will not turn on when i turn on him, instead I must click back button and again come into my app and then gps is on...that is the only reason for this restart activity